# Cant find table name when connecting android app with SQLite Database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to android programming so please help me. I have created database using SQLite browser, I am try to connecting my app with this database file, but it is not working, the error log say that "no such table : datasaya". How could this happen while in the database I created there is only 1 table.

**This my sqlite helper class:**

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static String DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.latihandbsqlite/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME = "cekdatabase.sqlite"; 
private static int VERSION =1; 
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext; 


public SQLiteHelper(Context context) { 

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION); 
    myContext = context; 

    try { 

        createDatabase(); 
        } catch (IOException ioe) { 

            throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
            } 
    } 

public void createDatabase() throws IOException { 

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(); 

    if (dbExist) { 
        System.out.println("DB EXIST"); 
        } else { 
            this.getReadableDatabase(); 
            this.close(); 
            copyDataBase(); 
            } 
    } 


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException { 

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int length; 
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {

        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length); 
        } 

    myOutput.flush(); 
    myOutput.close(); 
    myInput.close(); 
    } 

private boolean checkDataBase() { 

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null; 

    try { 

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, 
                null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 
        } catch (SQLiteException e) { 

            System.out.println("Database does't exist yet."); 
            } 

    if (checkDB != null) { 

        checkDB.close(); } 

    return checkDB != null ? true : false; 
    } 

@Override 

    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null) myDataBase.close(); 

        super.close(); 

    } @Override 

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) { 


    } @Override 

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 


    }

            }
```

**This my SQLiteConnector class:**

```
     public class SQLiteConnector {

private SQLiteDatabase database; 
private SQLiteHelper sqlHelper; 
private Cursor cursor; 

private static final String TABLE_RECORD = "datasaya"; 

public SQLiteConnector(Context context) { 

    sqlHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context); 

} // Getting All records 


public List<String> getAllRecord() { 

    List<String> namagambar = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORD; 

    database = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 

        do { 

            namagambar.add(cursor.getString(1)); 
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 

    } 
    database.close(); 
    return namagambar; 

} 

}
```

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Have you added Database in Assets?

Comment: i have added my database file in assets folder

Comment: ok and cross check your Table Name is match

Comment: i have checked my table name for many times, and its match

Comment: then only one thing to do uninstall your app and again install

Comment: i have done uninstall and install again my app, but its still error

Comment: then one thing is very clear that your DB never copied

Comment: when im runnging app for the 1st time after i install again said error " cant create database" but for the 2nd time it said " no such table :datasaya"

Comment: Well, then you need to investigate the "can't create database" error - as the database is not created correctly, obviously, your table will not exist in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the point of the name of your database. 
**From:** `cekdatabase.sqlite` **to:** `cekdatabase`.

Comment: To explain why it works: a new database file is created and an old one isn't reused.

Comment: sometimes, its work when use .sqlite, but sometime it wont work, why this happen ?